# Plotting histogram for categorical values

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using seaborn and I want to plot only categorical values (sex,smoker,day,time,size) with facet histogram (total 5 histogram on same place).

```
    import seaborn as sns
    tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
    tips
    
    # Plotting
    g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="sex",  row="smoker")
    g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, x="time")
```

[image]

I try with this line of code but this doesn't give me the results I expected. So can anybody help me with how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create subplots via matplotlib and fill them with the histograms?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
columns = ['sex', 'smoker', 'day', 'time', 'size']
sns.set()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=len(columns), figsize=(15, 5))
for ax, column in zip(axs, columns):
    sns.histplot(tips[column], discrete=True, ax=ax)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))  # set ticks at each position
    if ax != axs[0]:
        ax.set_ylabel('')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: histograms of 5 columns]